Theorem Involving Taylor Expansion
Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has n continuous derivatives. Show that for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exist polynomials $P$ & $Q$ of degree $n$ s.t. $P(x)\leq{f(x)}\leq{Q(x)}$ for all $x\in[x_0,x_0+\epsilon]$ and $Q(x)-P(x)=\lambda(x-x_0)^n$ for some $\lambda\geq{0}$.
I think I have the start of a proof for the theorem but I'm not quite sure.
My Proof: Expand $f(x)$ into a Taylor polynomial about $x_0$ to get $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k}+R_{n}^{x_0}(x)=P_{n-1}^{x_0}(x)+R_{n}^{x_0}(x)$$ where $R_n^{x_0}(x)=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ is the remainder term in the Lagrangian form, where $c$ is some number in between $x_0$ & $x$. If $f(c)\geq{0}$ define $$P(x)=P_{n-1}^{x_0}(x)+\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)^n$$ and $$Q(x)=P_{n-1}^{x_0}(x)+\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{(n-1)!}(x-x_0)^n.$$ For $f(c)<0$ we can do a similar case. Now because $(n-1)!\leq{n!}\leq{(n+1)!}$ we have $P(x)\leq{f(x)}\leq{Q(x)}.$ From here I don't really know what to do, I've proved the theorem for a point $x$ but to prove it for the interval maybe I could take a max of $f^{(n)}(x)$ on an interval?

The remainder term satisfies $$m{(x-x_0)^n\over n!}\le R_n\le M{(x-x_0)^n\over n!}$$ where $m=\min_{x_0\le t\le x_0+\varepsilon} f^n(t)$ and $M=\max_{x_0\le t\le x_0+\varepsilon} f^n(t).$ By adding the principal part of the Taylor expansion you obtain $P $ and $Q.$

I see, so $\epsilon$ can be chosen completely arbitrarily and we can find $P$ and $Q$?

It seems that $\varepsilon> 0$ is arbitrary. Perhaps there are some more requirements, not listed in your post. By the way there is a typo in OP Should be $Q-P.$

Whoops, my mistake that is a typo. As for the extra requirements I reviewed the textbook and the question is exactly as stated there. It seems it's just phrased oddly I guess, which is a shame because it confused me when trying to answer it. Thanks for the solution.

According to me the proper formulation should be: for any $x_0$ and any $\varepsilon>0$ ...
